# Proper way to escape query in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$sql = ("update Inventory SET  ? = ?+1 WHERE ID= ?");

$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($field,$field,$id))->affected_rows();
```

The error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''Upvotes' = 'Upvotes'+1 WHERE ID= 386464' at line 1

Basically it's adding quotes around the **Upvotes** field causing it to be a malformed query what's the most practical way to remove the single quotes or rewrite the query entirely?

Comment: Placeholders are for data only. Column names are handled differently.

Comment: ah how do i do it for column names?

Comment: You try not to. CodeGodie has a great answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers here arn't quite right, as they are expecting you to already have the upvote count. I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$this->db->where('ID', $ID);
$this->db->set('Upvotes', 'Upvotes+1', FALSE);
$this->db->update('Inventory');
```

Use the line below to confirm the output it should give you something like:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

﻿﻿﻿UPDATE `Inventory` SET `Upvotes` = Upvotes+1 WHERE `ID` = 386464

The third paramater of false tells CI to not protect the query with backticks.

Answer (score 2):

When possible, try to use CI's query builder to lower the chances of syntax errors. As per **[Codeigniter Documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update)**:

```
$data = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'name' => $name,
    'date' => $date
);

$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('Inventory', $data);
```

In your case, you are probably looking for something like this:

```
$data = array(
    'Upvotes' => $upvotes + 1
);

$this->db->where('CARD_ID', '386464');
$this->db->update('Inventory', $data);
```

Now, if you want to run a custom code that you cant run using CI's query builder class, then do this:

```
$custom_sql = "update Inventory SET Upvotes = Upvotes + 1 WHERE CARD_ID = 86464";
$query = $this->db->query($custom_sql);
```

Comment: This is the right idea. Whenever possible use the query generator rather than writing your own.

Comment: do I could say `$data = array( 'upvotes' = upvotes + 1)` which would increment the upvote count?

Comment: Yes you can, it would be `$data = array( 'upvotes' => $upvotes + 1)`, assuming that `$upvotes` is an integer variable

Comment: `Upvotes` needs to be retrieved by `ID` from the current row `Upvotes` column it's not passed in as an integer.

Comment: What? so you have an $id, and you want to retrieve the Upvotes from the database where ID = $id? I thought you wanted to UPDATE. Update and "retrieve" are opposites. With update you are changing the data that is already in the database, when you say "retrieve", you are just obtaining the data from the db

Comment: I do want to update I want to run this query : `update Inventory SET Upvotes = Upvotes+1 WHERE ID = 386464`

Comment: `upvotes` isn't a variable it doesn't exist until SQL fetches it by ID. Using this method I would need to run 2 queries 1 to fetch up-vote count and 1 to update it.

Comment: I see what you mean now.. I added an update to my answer